# Threads - Access resource avoiding starvation

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I know that this isn't a "homework helper website", but I got insane in the last days because i have to implement the access to resource avoiding starvation and i can't figure out how to do that. Can anyone help me with some application examples or documentation? The assignment is: a resource may be used by 2 types of processes: black and white. When the resource is used by the white processes, it can not be used by the black processes and vice-versa. Implement the access to the resource avoiding starvation. Is this a producer-consumer case?

Comment: Do you understand what the symptoms of starvation would be?

Comment: SO is a "homework helper website" as long as you let us know it's homework and accept the fact that we'll try not to give you the solution directly but rather lead you on the right path, help you understand the basics (or what ever is evading you at the moment) and make you work for it.

Comment: As far as read, starvation is the condition in which one or more threads do not make progress. Is equally-problematic with the deadlock.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Let's make a few assumptions (for the sake of discussion):

- Our processes will be threads -- not actual software processes, there's a difference which may be important in your assignment.
- White processes are Readers.
- Black processes are Writers.
- Our common resource is particular Variable.

### Mutual exclusion locks ([mutex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion)):

A mutex is a type of exclusive lock, it has a binary state, it's either locked or unlocked. You can lock it, unlock it or check to see if it's locked or not.

Threads can lock each other out using mutex (mutual exclusion locks) just as processes can lock each other out using semaphores.

When you want to protect a variable from being used by two threads at once you create a mutex for that variable and write every thread so that it attempts to lock the mutex before attempting to use the variable and unlock it after they're done.

This makes any first thread lock the mutex and any subsequent thread block until the first thread unlocks the mutex basically forcing all of these threads to line up and operate on that particular variable sequentially.

This is a bit ineffective when you just want to read the variable, not change its value, because two threads reading the same content doesn't create any conflict or invalid data. Two threads writing at the same time might however corrupt the data.

### [Readers/Writers locks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Readers%E2%80%93writer_lock) (RWL):

Most implementations of Readers/Write locks will use a shared lock and an exclusive lock, but they expose a simple usage approach: if you want to read grab a "read lock", if you want to write grab a "write lock".

"Read locks" are not exclusive and they allow multiple readers to be reading at one particular time (without blocking).

"Write locks" are exclusive and only one writer can be writing at one particular time (without blocking).

### Starvation:

- First step: Readers/Writers Locks is the event when a first (read) thread grabs a "read lock" on the variable, a second (write) tries to grab a "write lock" but is blocked until all readers finish reading.
- Second step: before the first thread finishes reading, a third (read) thread grabs a "read lock" on the variable; this means the second (write) thread has to wait for this third thread to finish.

Repeat the second step until starvation is achieved.

### Avoiding starvation with [Seqlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Seqlock):

A seqlock is implemented with one mutex and some counters. It always allows reading, even while the writers are writing to the variable but it gives the readers a means of checking if the data has been written to during the time it was being read, if so it may be corrupt so the readers will have to reread the data and check for consistency again.

The "read & consistency check" phase runs in a loop until the check confirms consistency of the data, at which point the reader can continue with its usual task.

The writers use the mutex to grab exclusive access so they never overlap their operations.

This is good for high read low write situations. If there would be too many writers the readers would continuously loop rereading the data.

### Your particular situation:

If black processes need to be able to share the resource among themselves and white processes need to be able to share the resource among themselves but white processes can't share the resource with black processes then the solution will not be either RWL or Seqlock.

A variation on the Seqlock algorithm might be your solution.

Answer (score 0):

Generally, is a problem in which it comes to access a shared resource (or mutex).

If you have two object of the same class, both threads:

pseudo-code:

```
loop 
   if shared_resource is free
      lock shared_resource
      do something
      free shared_resource
```

This in VERY broad terms!